# How can I get the id from a select2 dropdown

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I want to get the associated id for a selected value in a [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) dropdown. Is this possible?

```
    $mySelect2.on("change",function(){
        var textValue = $(this).val(); //works
        console.log($(this).select2('id'));// ????
    });
```

Comment: this.options is undefined

Comment: can you provide code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  var theID = $(this).select2('data').id;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/platypusman/xDUUg/